# Extremely safe Postgres permissioning

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, security, permissions

Let's say that I have four tables in my Postgres database, two of which are private and contain highly sensitive information (`private1` and `private2`), and two that contain information I want to allow anyone in the world to be able to query arbitrarily (`public1` and `public2`). I'm aware that this is a very poor design, but bear with me.

I want to set up a user that can solely run `SELECT`s on the two public tables, but can in no way do anything else even remotely malicious with the other two tables (or the database more generally).

My naive approach would be to do something like set up a new user `public_querier`, run a `REVOKE ALL ON private1, private2, public1, public2 FROM public_querier;` and then a `GRANT SELECT ON public1, public2 TO public_querier;`.

My sneaking suspicion is that this does not fulfill my security desideratum because of some subtleties that I don't have knowledge of, and I'd greatly appreciate a spot check on that suspicion.

Cheers!

Comment: You'll probably get better answers at dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Securing data in a database while also exposong it to users is way more complex than setting database permissions. This question is too broad and cannot be answered well in this form.

Comment: @GaborLengyel understood – do you have any references that would help explain how one might go about implementing what I described above?

Answer (score 0):

You can only revoke permissions that were previously granted.

Use `\z table_name` in `psql` to examine the permissions.

If you see nothing, the table has the default permissions: only the table owner can access it.

In that case, grant `SELECT` to the public tables to the role and do nothing about the private tables.

If there are already permissions granted on the private tables, revoke them as desired.